# libssh vs alternative root users

Tags: shell, ssh

Here is an excerpt of the /etc/passwd file on a remote machine.

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
valid:x:0:0::/home/valid:/bin/rbash
```

As you can see, valid is an alternative name for root.

I can ssh to any of the accounts with a regular ssh command:

```
ssh root@remoteMachine
[...]
# whoami
root
# pwd
/root
```

and

```
ssh valid@remoteMachine
[...]
> whoami
<command unknown>
> pwd
<command unknown>
```

(we disabled the commands with rbash)

Now, however, when connecting to the remoteMachine as user "valid" with libssh, remote-running `whoami` returns `root`, and `pwd` returns `/home/admin`. It also appears the shell everything runs in is rbash (found with `ps -ef | grep tototototo`)

The question is: is this some kind of a bug in libssh, or is it a bug in ssh that won't appear in command-line ssh ?

Comment: That's weird: the shell is enforced by the server, and the client should have no way to know that `valid` and `root` are the same user. What unix variant and ssh implementation is the server running? Can you post the server logs (from `/var/log/auth.log` or similar)? Do you have any aliases in `~/.ssh/config`? Have you checked that no multiplexing is being done?

Comment: @Gilles:  
Here is what I have:  

client side:  
`$ uname -a  
Linux Debian6 2.6.32-5-686 #1 SMP Mon Jun 13 04:13:06 UTC i686 GNU/Linux  
$ ssh -v  
OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian6, OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010`  

Server side:  
`$ uname -a  
Linux #Company Name# 2.6.32-33-generic #72_Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 29 21:08:37 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux  
$ ssh -v  
OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian_3ubuntu7, OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009`  
  
There is no /home/admin/.ssh directory.  
/root/.ssh contains no configure file/directory.

Comment: @Gilles: When running my code on client side, here are the logs in `/var/log/auth.log`:  
  
  
`Accepted password for valid from 192.168.1.20 port 33513 ssh2  
  
pass_unix (sshd:session) session opened for user valid by (uid=0)  
  
pass_unix (sshd:session) session closed for user valid` 

Now, the only thing that changes is that, when I use the command line ssh, the port number changes. (to something in the lines of 57337)

Comment: What's the output of the following command: `ssh valid@remoteMachine 'echo $BASHOPTS; echo $BASH $HOME; whoami'`? Does it change if you pass the option `-t` to `ssh`? What if you run ssh interactively and type these commands? And with libssh? What do the startup files in `/home/admin` contain (`.profile`, `,bash_profile`, `.bash_login`, `.bashrc`)?